# Availability of file for each user directory on bash

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

I have an idea, how to check availability of "id_rsa.pub" for each user in home directory. But something does not work. 
My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

users=`ls /home/`

for i in "$users"; do
if [[ -f "/home/$i/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" ]]; then
    echo "All users have this key"
else
    echo "Users $i don't have this key, We need build key for this users"
fi
done
```

In the debug:

```
+ [[ -f /home/donovan
valeri
john
roman
colbi
testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ]]
```

How i see, it takes a full path, but don't  full path for each user. Please help, what i do wrong ? Thanks for your attention.
And of course, i have a result:

```
Users donovan
valeri
john
roman
colbi
testuser don't have this key, We need build key for this users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are causing all usernames to be seen as a single string:

```
for i in "$users"; do
```

Remove the quotes and it works:

```
for i in $users; do
```

Usernames don't contain spaces, so you should be safe here.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls /home` is not a good idea to use in scripts. `ls` is a human-readable listing command and not meant to be used in scripts.

You can simply create an array and loop through the indices e.g

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

users=(/home/*)

for i in "${users[@]}"; do
if [[ -f "$i/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" ]]; then
    echo "All users have this key"
else
    echo "Users $i don't have this key, We need build key for this users"
fi
done
```

Comment: I'd go one further and validate that they are actually users like `users=( $(getent passwd | awk -F: '($3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 65000){print $6}') )`